# Определить, подключен ли Сокет UDP, не используя Try-Catch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio, сокет

Приветствую.

Есть конструкция:

```
IPEndPoint Address = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Ip), (int)Port);
Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.Connect(Address);
 //Send
byte[] recvData = new byte[1400];
int recv = socket.Receive(recvData);
```

Если удалённый сервер выключен, кидает исключение на строчки `int recv = socket.Receive(recvData);`:
*Необработанное исключение типа "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" в System.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.*

Каким образом можно избежать исключение, не используя конструкцию Try-Catch (влияет на производительность в моем случае).

Пробовал такое, но не работает:

```
bool SocketConnected(Socket s)
    {
        bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
        bool part2 = (s.Available == 0);
        if (part1 && part2)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: @updat, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

А чем Вас пугает обработка исключения? Каким образом оно так сильно съедает у Вас производительность? Может, неправильно используете? И как Вам быть в ситуации, когда сервер выключается уже в процессе передачи? Тут по любому будет исключение, и его надо обрабатывать.

**Обновление**

Так в том то и дело, что проверить, отключён хост у вас или нет, можно только по таймауту или пока сам сервер не скажет вам быстро, что недоступен. Исключения тут ни при чём. Попробуйте поискать настройку таймаута, но тогда вы тоже не можете гарантировать, что сервер просто не тупанул или связь тупит. Сервер может работать, но пинг у него может быть ужасный.

Comment: Исключение не нравится, потому что есть список ip, port. Нужно проверить, какой хост онлайн, а какой нет, и получить инфо от хоста, который онлайн. Если делать это через исключения, то занимает много времени на отключенные хосты... Если хост отключится во время передачи или приема, то я обязательно повешу поверх кода на такой случай Try-Catch, но никак не проверять методом Try-Catch, онлайн ли хост или нет.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что проверить, отключён хост у вас или нет, можно только по таймауту или пока сам сервер не скажет вам быстро, что недоступен. Исключения тут ни при чём. Попробуйте поискать настройку таймаута, но тогда вы тоже не можете гарантировать, что сервер просто не тупанул или связь тупит. Сервер может работать, но пинг у него может быть ужасный.